# Google search like text box

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

am want to create a text box like google search text box...

What i have tried is When entered a character, using AJAX the words starting with that word will be displayed in a div its working fine but i want that it should work exactly like google search box.. Now the arrow keys are not working only by clicking the text will be selected

MY CODE

```
<style>
#resultDiv {
width:154px;
position:absolute;
left:121px;
top:30px;
}

p {
padding:0px;
margin:0px;
}
#resultDiv p:hover {
background-color:#999;
}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(e) {
$('#resultDiv p').live('click',function(){
    var value = $(this).text();
    $('#word').val(value);
});
});
</script>

</head>

<body>
<form action="" method="post">
<label>Enter Your Word </label><input type="text" id="word"/>
<div id="resultDiv"></div>
</form>

<script>
// prepare the form when the DOM is ready 
$(document).ready(function() { 
$('#word').keyup(function(e) {
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "googleDropSearch.php",
        data: "word="+this.value,
        success: function(msg){
            $('#resultDiv').html(msg);
            $('#resultDiv').css('border-left','1px solid #ccc').css('border-right','1px solid #ccc').css('border-bottom','1px solid #ccc');
        }
    });
});
});

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

ACTION PAGE

```
<?php
$connection = mysql_connect('localhost','root','') or die("ERROR".mysql_error());
$connection = mysql_select_db('ajax',$connection) or die("ERROR".mysql_error());

if(!empty($_POST)):
if(isset($_POST['word']) && $_POST['word'] != ''):
/****************
Sanitize the data
***************/
$key =$_POST['word'];
$query = mysql_query("SELECT county FROM fl_counties WHERE county LIKE '$key%';");

 $rows = mysql_num_rows($query);
 if($rows != 0):
while($result = mysql_fetch_array($query)):

echo "<p>".$result[0]."</p>";
endwhile;
endif;//rows > 0


endif;//county not sent

endif;


?>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions for new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun the [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ). See the [**red box**](http://goo.gl/GPmFd)? Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you can't decide, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help to choose. If you care to learn, [here is good PDO tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC).

Comment: You are already using jquery. Pick yourself one of the autocomplete plugins, extend it to your needs. It's called free software because you can change it your own.

Comment: `live()` is also deprecated in favour of `on()`

Comment: I had the same problem. This question helped me alot. Thanks. Please don't negative vote such questions. Use your voting power wisely. Also I request the questioner to accept the below answer as it seems to be the appropriate answer. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

There is one useful plugin available in jquery.

[Jquery Autocomplete](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/)

There is simple demo available you just have to pass an array to it.

Hope this would work for you.